# I can't understand why "FindRoot::nlnum:" shows up in my code

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve a system of equations using Findroot as follows:

```
Clear[a]; Clear[c]; n = 2;
SysEqn1 = Table[a[i] + I Sum[(PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + 0.5))] + 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + (2 \[Pi] - 1.2)))] - 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.3))] - 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.4))]), {i, n}], {j, n}];
SysEqn2 = Table[c[i] + I Sum[(PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + 0.5))] + 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + (2 \[Pi] - 1.2)))] - 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.3))] - 
    PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.4))]), {i, n}], {j, n}];
SysEqn = Join[SysEqn1, SysEqn2]; 
startingValues1 = Table[{a[i], -1 + 2 i/n}, {i, n}]; 
startingValues2 = Table[{c[i], -0.9 + 2 i/n}, {i, n}]; 
starting = Join[startingValues1, startingValues2];
FindRoot[SysEqn, starting]
```

The error message from the above code is as fo

```
FindRoot::nlnum: "The function value {a[i]+(0. +1.\ I)\ (1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]+1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]-1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]-1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]+1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]+1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]-1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]-1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]),a[i]+(0. +1.\ I)\ (<<1>>),<<1>>,c[i]+(0. +1.\ I)\ (1.\ Log[1. +Times[<<2>>]]+<<11>>)} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {4} at {a[1],a[2],c[1],c[2]} = {0.,1.,0.1,1.1}."
```

For n=2 case, I have four equations so I think the number of starting variables that should be determined is also four. But for some reason my code doesn't work... I would really appreciate if you can help me out with this problem!

Comment: "I have no idea how to write the summation symbol here" - re-express them with `Sum[]`, and then copy it here. Otherwise, I guarantee no one is going to bother trying to re-type all of that just to help you.

Comment: See [`How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site`](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/9362)

Comment: I put you edit with your original question.  (That's how the site is supposed to work: you edit your question to fix it up.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there seems to be a bug:

```
PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[1] - a[2] + (2 π - 1.2)))]
(*  -1. Log[1 - 2.71828^((0. + 1. I) (5.08319 - 1. a[2.] + c[1.]))]  *)
```

Note the indices have been converted from `Integer` to `Real` numbers.  This can be easily fixed with [`NHoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldAll.html).

Second, there's an `a[i]` and `c[i]` at the beginning of `Table` in each system, but the `Table` iterator is `j`.  Looking at the image posted in the original form of the question, it seems the `j` iterator for the `Sum` was misplaced in the edit.

```
ClearAll[a];
ClearAll[c];
SetAttributes[a, NHoldAll];
SetAttributes[c, NHoldAll];
n = 2;
SysEqn1 = Table[a[i] + I Sum[(PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + 0.5))] + 
        PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + (2 π - 1.2)))] - 
        PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.3))] - 
        PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.4))]), {j, n}], {i, n}];
SysEqn2 = Table[c[i] + I Sum[(PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + 0.5))] + 
        PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] + (2 π - 1.2)))] - 
        PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.3))] - 
        PolyLog[1, E^(I (c[j] - a[i] - 0.4))]), {j, n}], {i, n}];
SysEqn = Join[SysEqn1, SysEqn2];
startingValues1 = Table[{a[i], -1 + 2 i/n}, {i, n}];
startingValues2 = Table[{c[i], -0.9 + 2 i/n}, {i, n}];
starting = Join[startingValues1, startingValues2];

FindRoot[SysEqn, starting]
(*
  {a[1] -> 1.8484 + 0.907529 I, a[2] -> 3.0128 + 1.14394 I, 
   c[1] -> 1.8484 + 0.907529 I, c[2] -> 3.0128 + 1.14394 I}
*)
```

Comment: I don't know if making the indices of `a` and `c` into reals is a bug or not. It goes back at least to V9. It also happens with `ChebyshevT`, but not with `BesselJ`. One could check other indexed families of functions.

Comment: Oh, I found that the error message still shows up without "SetAttributes" even though i and j are swapped. But with "SetAttributes" it looks like there is no problem. Thanks a lot!!